# Volvo XC40 T5. 2018 immobilizer troubleshooting

Tags: troubleshooting, volvo, immobilizer

With all the 3 keys it's not possible to start the engine. Batteries on the keys were replaced and it works well to open and closed the doors. The only way to start the car is now to place the key in the central box between the seats, as described to do in case of an empty key battery. What's could be necessary to repair?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds as though the transceiver for the car may be having a tough time either energizing the key or receiving the feedback once the key is energized. I'm not sure if your Volvo is a push button start or not? (Proximity with a push button versus inserting the key to twist and start.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind feedback. The car is equipped with a push botton only, without inserting. Someone told to me that the expensive outdoor roof radio antenna is also responsible for the immobilizer transceiver, but nothing on Volvo manuals indicates it. I appreciate a lot if somebody have more info.

Comment: Meanwhile I findout that when I keep the key near the push botton the car starts. As soon the key is just 5 inches away from the push botton the message " Car key is not recognized" appears  but the car drives.

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: Here's a link for help; https://www.youcanic.com/vehicle/volvo-immobilizer-see-manual-problem. Alldata.diy or Mitchell data provide online service manuals for a reasonable fee whether for a day, week or longer. Auto electric repair shops or mobile techs specializing in factory anti theft systems can help too and of course your nearest Volvo dealer for dealer support.

Comment: Volvo dealer is stiil in trouble and from June can not solve this problem. They said they await an answer from Sweden for 3 different cars with the same problem. It takes a long time...

Answer (score 0):

low battery, car or fob will cause immobilizer to shut car down and lots more. do you have a scanner to check, ECU and immobilizer? it will tell you more. and  probably give you info you are looking for. just make sure you buy one that will talk to you car. there are none that will do all. first use of it will save you. dealer charges around 175.00 just to scan. and they are simple to use.